# How to return just a nested property in field using Collection.find()

Tags: mongodb, meteor

There is a way to return only a nested property of field using `collection.find()`?  I have stored some information inside `users` collection, specifically inside `profile` field I added the property: `imagepath`.

So I want to do a publish of users collection showing the `username` and only the property `imagepath` inside `profile` (Profile have additional information, not sensitive but bulky).

```
Meteor.publish('UsersInfo', function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({},{fields:{username:1, profile.imagepath:1}});
});
```

Issue: the `profile.image` is not recognized as field in the query.

Comment: You need to wrap "profile.imagepath" in quotes

Comment: It works! Thanks @pintxo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `profile.imagepath` in quotes. I.e: `"profile.imagepath"`